# Retrieving earlier Chrome bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

In preparation for performing a clean install of Windows 7 32-bit, I took an image backup of my existing Windows XP SP3 hard drive. The clean install did away with all my Chrome bookmarks, of course. Is there a way to retrieve the old bookmarks I had in XP? What files would I access in the image backup? And how can I import them into the Windows 7 Chrome bookmark file?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7, your Chrome profile should be located at \Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default <sup>1</sup>. Inside that folder, there should be a "Bookmarks" file. If you have not created bookmarks in the Chrome profile in your clean installation, you could directly overwrite the file in the new profile with your backed up copy.

[1]: See http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory for information on where Chrome profiles are located in all operating systems.